# React - render() not called with setState with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch an array of movies and after it fetches the list it updates the state and the list should render, but the problem is the render method never calls from inside the axios callback, here is my code below

```
export default class Movies extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state={movies:[]};
    }

    componentDidMount(){

      axios.get('URL')
            .then(response => {
              this.setState({movies:response.data});
              console.log("Movies",this.state);// I get the values here see screenshot..

      });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          <MovieList movies={this.state.movies}/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">Movie Details</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the code above, in function `componentDidMount` in the axios callback I am setting the response values to the state, but it doesn't call the render after doing it, the block does execute well as I get the log properly see screenshot below
[image]

I am not understanding why it doesn't call `render()` ? I have tried couple of solutions available but none works for me, if I hardcode the videos array in default state it works fine, please help if anyone know the solution.

**Update(Adding MovieList Code)**

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <li className="list-group-item">{this.props.moviename}</li>
    );
  }
}

export default class MoviesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Props",props);
    this.state={movies:props.movies};
  }

  renderList(){

    const items=this.state.movies.map((movie) => <ListItem moviename={movie.name} key={movie.name}/>);

    return items;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item"><h3>Movies</h3></li>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show `MovieList` component how you are rendering movies array? put a `console.log('render')` inside render method it will print once you do `setState`.

Comment: Make sure your movie components inside MovieList have a key so React can know what to re-render. (Edited thanks to @azium)

Comment: @Storm MovieList should not have a key. the children inside probably do if it's an array of components

Comment: I would expect this to be a problem in `MovieList`.

Comment: It seems to me that your `MovieList` component is not updating itself. What if you try to check it's `componentWillReceiveProps` method if it is getting new `movies` prop and make it `forceUpdate` itself there?

Comment: Please update your question in order to fix this problem. We need both scripts.

Comment: Yes updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are getting is in ListItem Component.
In order to get it work you need to work with [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

In this case, construct is called **only once**
Because of that your component won't update. You need to use function componentWillReceiveProps , this function will run every time component receive new data.

Example:

```
componentwillreceiveprops(nextProps){
 this.setState({
   movies: nextProps.movies
})
}
```

Comment: This works but I guess you have typo? will it be `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

Comment: True, just changed it. Thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1):

Did you added `componentWillReceiveProps` in `MovieList`?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making your MoviesList stateless:

```
export default class MoviesList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Props",props);
    //If your component won't alter movies list by itself - there's no point to manage its "state"
    //this.state={movies:props.movies};
  }

  renderList(){
    //Use props here instead
    const items=this.props.movies.map((movie) => <ListItem moviename={movie.name} key={movie.name}/>);
    return items;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item"><h3>Movies</h3></li>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Generally, you should strive to dumbing-down your components whenever possible.

Comment: I don't think it's a good way of working with React. You should separate your code in small components. (I talk about big projects)

Comment: That's the point of having small stateless components at the base of your hierarchy. You only want to mess with the state if the data cannot be propagated down from the parent component, which is not the case

Comment: @StasParshin Yes it can be used as stateless component, I was just trying sample of code to make it work, practically it should be mixture of both type of components.

Comment: @StasParshin But in this case I don't know how `render()` method of `MoviesList` will get called if I don't use state? can you elaborate?

Comment: Movies would be your stateful component. Once it's state changes - it will propagate changes to the MoviesList throught its props. Since props are now different - the MoviesList's render() will get called.